# Linux: convert pfx to snk - or: How to Strong-Name an Assembly

Tags: c#, linux, mono, code-signing, x509certificate2

I am on Linux. The platform is a devcontainer, so the underlying os might vary.

I am using `dotnet build` to compile a `.csproj` project. (The `.csproj` is in the new sdk format.)

I need the resulting assembly to be strong-named. However, I only have a password protected `.pfx` file (and I know the password).

**How do I convert that `.pfx` file into something the `dotnet` tool can digest on Linux?**

Direct signing with `.pfx` does not seem to be supported. It seems I need a `.snk` file that is not password-protected. However, after spending several hours with Google and ChatGPT, I seem unable to find a way to create a `.snk` file that contains both the public and the private key from the `.pfx` file. And I am still unsure whether the `.snk` file is the correct way to go.

Can anyone here help me figure this out? Again, this is Linux, not Windows. On Windows this would be easy(er).

***Platform:***

- some Linux os
- mono installed (includes the sn tool)
- OpenSSL installed
- dotnet installed
- PowerShell installed

Other open-source tools can be added if needed.

***Input:***

- `something.cs`
- `something.csproj`
- `aPasswordProtected.pfx`

***Output:***

- a strong-name signed .dll file

***Process:***

- there are several possible paths to go from here. I don't have a preference at this point.

  - Convert the key, and reference the converted file in the `.csproj` file.
  - Convert the key. Use `dotnet build` to create unsigned Assembly. Use other tool to sign the assembly after the fact.
  - Use yet another tool alltogether to both compile and sign.

Also at this point I am not concerned with security. Let's get it working first. Then we can think about how to store unprotected key files safely.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Creating a `.snk` file requires an intermediary step making a `.pem` file (without a password). Here is the PowerShell script:

```
& openssl pkcs12 -in "$pfxFilePath" -out "$pemFilePath" -nodes -passin pass:$pfxPassword

$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$pemContent = Get-Content -Path "$pemFilePath" -Raw

$rsa.ImportFromPem($pemContent.ToCharArray())
$keyPair = $rsa.ExportCspBlob($true)

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($snkFilePath, $keyPair)
```

This `.snk` file you can directly reference in you `.csproj` file like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly> 
  <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>$(snkFilePath)</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Pass the $snkFilePath into `dotnet` like this (in PowerShell):

```
& dotnet build /p:snkFilePath=$snkFilePath
```